# ¿Cómo conectarse a una base de datos Access 2007 en Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Tengo este código para conectar con la base de datos de Access 2007 y extraer de la `Tabla_simbolos` las columnas `id` y `simbolos`, pero me da varios problemas. No se como solucionarlo, no conozco mucho de programación.

```
 Sub SelectX1()

    Dim dbs As DataTable, rst As Recordset
    Dim OpenDatabase As DataRow
    Dim EnumFields As Integer

   dbs = OpenDatabase("proyecto1DataSet.mdb")


    rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Id, " _
        & "Simbolos FROM Tabla_simbolos;")


    rst.MoveLast()


    EnumFields(rst, 12)
    Lexico.Letras.Text = dbs
    dbs.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor, ten en cuenta que nosotros no tenemos la información de contexto que tú tienes y "me da varios problemas" no nos sirve de mucho para poder ayudarte. ¿Podrías ser más específico? ¿Qué problemas te da exactamente? Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Konamiman ese problema ya me lo ayudaron a solventar, el problema que tengo ahora es que no se como hacer para que esas columnas de la tabla aparezcan en un combobox.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo es que estas mezclando dos tecnologias diferentes, por un lado veo que usas `ADO.NET` con los `datatable` y por otro usas `ADODB` (la cual usabas en `VB6`) cuando defines `Recordset`

Mi recomendacion es que solo uses `ADO.NET`, ADODB solo se mentiene por compatibilidad con desarrollos legacy, pero no deberias usarlo

```
Function SelectX1() As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string")
        Dim query AsString = "SELECT Id, Simbolos FROM Tabla_simbolos;"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    Return dt

End Sub
```

Como veras alli solo se usa `ado.net` usando el `DataAdapter` para realizar el `Fill()` del datatable.

Para definir el conection string podrias guiarte por

[Access 2007 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/)

No estoy muy seguro que hace la linea `Lexico.Letras.Text = dbs`, pero me suena raro que asignes a una propiedad .Text un datatable

Comment: Entiendo eso de que estaba usando 2 tecnologias diferentes, lo que queria hacer con esa linea es mostrar la base de datos en un combobox que tengo que se llama letras.

Comment: con lo que explico podrias cargar el datatable y asignar este al DataSource del combo. Pero debes usar ado.net

Comment: @Jose95Madrid al ver unas preguntas tuyas marcadas con -1 recientes (no hablo de que sean correctos o no) y revisar tu perfil puede que te interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/help en el apartado preguntas por otro lado he visto que tienes cuatro preguntas y todas ellas han sido constestadas por LeandroTuttini, por eso podrias leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y asi enteder a lo que me refiero, podrias votar a favor si crees que alguna respuesta ayudo a solucionar tu problema y/o marcarla como aceptada (no es obligatorio pero creo que es aconsejable). Saludos

Comment: Entiendo gracias @AngelAngel

Comment: @LeandroTuttini conecte la base de datos y intente utilizar Lexico.Letras.DataSource = dt
 para que lo mostrara en el combobox, no me da error pero no me muestra nada

Comment: Si defines un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas el datatable luego de pasar por el Fill() puede validar que hay alguna row creada ? imagino la tabla en la db tiene registros

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Si tiene registros la tabla, pero no se como validar las columnas

Comment: Validar las columnas ? si es para realizar una prueba simplemente podrias usar el SELECT * FROM y cargar todas las columnas, para ver al menos que tengas registroas